# Get timestamp from yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript

I need to get unix timestamp from yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss time.

I know There are many ways to get timestamp.

But I need to get timestamp without using `new Date()` way.

For example,

```
new Date("2019-10-25 00:00:00").getTime() / 1000
```

Asia/Seoul time and other countries value return same value.

I also tried to use momentJS with timezone like this.

```
moment().tz('Asia/Seoul').valueOf()
moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').valueOf()
```

How can I get timestamp without using like above code?

Comment: Why don't you use momentJS?

Comment: Why can't you use `new Date`...? Would code/libraries that ultimately use the `Date` object also be not usable?

Comment: @CristianTraìna I tried to use momentJs. When I use timezone, There is problem to use that valueOf or format('x') data is always same data.

Comment: I thought Seoul timestamp of time and LA timestamp are different, but return same timestamp.

Comment: You can try this library - [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/dev/docs/ko/README-ko.md). It just 2kb size.

Comment: a `timestamp` is the number of (milli)seconds since *Jan 1 1970 0:00:00 UTC* - the so, a timestamp of `0` is `midnight Jan 1 1970 UTC` - it is also `10:00:00 AM Jan 1 1970 UTC+10`  .... but that is the same moment in time on planet earth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As statet in `moment-timezone` [DOCS](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/):

> moment.tz(..., String) is used to create a moment with a time zone. It
>   takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the
>   last argument as a time zone identifier:

```js
const timestamp1 = moment.tz("2019-10-25 00:00:00", "Asia/Taipei").format('X');
const timestamp2 = moment.tz("2019-10-25 00:00:00", "America/Toronto").format('X');

console.log(timestamp1);
console.log(timestamp2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.26/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's better - use moment timezone to indicate the input timezone!!

Comment: Because: OP needs timezones, MomentJS is a industry standard, managing timezones and transform with MomentJS make it more readable.

Comment: I've hit "post answer" by mistake